# Automatically set Homepage

Tags: homepage

I want when I publish any page, it also set as homepage automatically in my wordpress website..
please help

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `update_option` for that. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/

```
function set_home_page($post_id) {
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $post_id );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
 }
add_action( 'publish_post', 'set_home_page' );
```

Comment: Hai, yes same I want to use, but I am not a programmer, so can you provide some code, that I can put. Main main goal is, when I publish any page it automatically set as home page. Thanks in advance bro. Please help